# sorting uploaded images in accordion symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, symfony

I have a problem about sorting the images I upload into their respective places in the accordion.
In my twig I have a table containing the list of entries I input:

```
 {% for row in AddCategoryTable %}    
            <section class="section {% block class_stickers %}{% endblock %}">
                <p class="title">
                    <a href="#">{{row.input}}</a>
```

here every input I make, a section in the accordion will be added containing the input I made, ex: I input "cars" in my form, a section car will appear in the accordion.
So in this for loop, I have another for loop for the images

```
 {% for image in CategoryImageTable %}
                        <div style="height:60px;width:60px; position:relative; display: inline-block;margin: 3px;">   

                            <img src="{{ path('z_category_image', {'image':image.id}) }}" style="position:absolute;height:60px;width:60px;"/>
```

I get that this part is somewhat wrong. The way this code works is that It goes with the 1st loop, so for each input I have for the "AddCategoryTable" the image will loop with it.

My form for the upload also has an entity type dropdown  that contains data from the AddCategory table. So basically it goes like this: **Add category input ----> Category image dropdown, the formtype that has the dropdown also has a file type field that lets you upload files**

what I want to happen is to be able to specify where the image will go in the accordion using the dropdown to direct where the image goes.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance

P.S. if this is somewhat unclear i'm sorry